# Invalid decimal validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I wrote an application with model validation, but when i try to enter decimal values i'm getting

> The value '12.12' is not valid for Price.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required.")]
[Range(0, 9999.99)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: what's your culture?

Comment: i tried to add  <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/> in web.config, but still getting same error

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled on this again after 2 years. I thought ASP.NET MVC 5 had solved this but looks like it's not the case. So here goes how to solve the problem.

Create a class called DecimalModelBinder like the following and add it to the root of your project for example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespace
{   
    public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

            object actualValue = null;

            if(valueResult.AttemptedValue != string.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }
                catch(FormatException e)
                {
                    modelState.Errors.Add(e);
                }
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);

            return actualValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside Global.asax.cs, make use of it in `Application_Start()` like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, so i added in my Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
});
```

and

```
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

in dotnet core mvc 5 and above you can set `NumberDecimalSeparator="."`

```
var supportedCultures = new[] { "ar", "es" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
           
localizationOptions.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator=".";
    
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Comment: this answer worked for me. So all I need to do is include all the cultures in that array right? In my layout.cshtml lang set as "en". So is that mean in that array only "en" is enfough? Here is the question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059570/decimal-values-are-not-accepting-in-input-type-number-why?noredirect=1#comment132471360_75059570       Your answer is working. So is it ok if I forcibly saying to decimal seaprator as dot?