# Decimal values are not accepting in input type Number. Why?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have below input type in asp.net core application

```
<form asp-controller="~/Controllers/GroupLengthConverterTools/MToCmController">
    <p>Provide the meter value below</p>
    <span asp-validation-for="InputValue" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="number" asp-for="InputValue" id="numberCounter" step="any" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" /><br />


    <br />
    <input asp-action="Index" type="submit" value="Convert to Centimeters" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <input asp-action="Clear" type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
    <br />
</form>
```

Here is the controller class

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("meter-to-cm")]
        public IActionResult Index(LengthConverterBassModel model)
        {
            model.SetToolModelData(model, toolUniqueIdentifier);
            ModelState["InputText"].ValidationState = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Valid;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(FullPathsOfViews.MToCmLengthConverter, model);
            }

            model.OutPutText = string.Format("{0}cm - {1}", LengthConverters.ConvertMToCm(model.InputValue);

            return View(FullPathsOfViews.MToCmLengthConverter, model);
        }
```

After I type 4.56 into the box it says an error

> The value '4.56' is not valid for InputValue.

Below is the Model class

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide a value")]
public decimal? InputValue { get; set; }
```

Note that this was not happening in localhost. Only when I deployed this. Both regions are set to the United states.

When this occures even the public IActionResult Index(LengthConverterBassModel model) method is not firing. It stops at the presentation layer.
Whats wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the codes you've shown,could you provide more codes related?

Comment: What's the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUiCulture` in your controller?

Comment: @Corvus I catched the culture info and displayed on the UI. But the button click is not hitting the method if there is a decimal part in the number. it give the error "The value '2.3' is not valid for InputValue." InputValue is the model property which this is binded for and its decimal. Without putting the decimal part, method fired and currentUIculture is en-US

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Kindly see the question again. I updated the question

Comment: What's your .net vsersion and uiculture?I still coun't reproduce the error in .net 6,but I found a related case here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126137/decimal-value-is-not-valid-for-price-mvc3